# C++ How to pass empty array as default argument in a function

Tags: c++, c++11, multidimensional-array

I'm new to C++ and I want to create a function that takes an empty array of a certain size as default value. Basically the array should act like a storage for the iterative function calls and the function will return some value in that array at the end. I need an empty array because my function is going to be recursive.

I tried the following code but it didn't work, the problem lies with `int& M[a][b]` and I don't know what's the correct way to define my empty array.

```
#include<iostream>

void foo(const int& a, const int& b, int (&M)[a][b]){
    std::cout<<a<<'\n';
}
int main(){
    int M[2][3];
    foo(2,3,M);
}
```

Here's the error message

```
 error: cannot bind rvalue '(int)((int (*)[3])(& M))' to 'int&'
```

Comment: What do you mean by "empty array"?  Arrays are fixed in size.

Comment: The size of fixed (statically sized) arrays must be known at compile time (ex `constexpr`). In c++ you can use `std::array` (`std::vector` in case the size is not known at compile time).

Comment: `void foo(const int& a, const int&b, std::vector<std::vector<int>>& M)`

Comment: For what it's worth, your question contains neither an empty array nor a default argument ;-). So I'm confused: Is your question body still incomplete (i.e., does not contain an example of the actual problem), or did you write something in the title that does not exactly describe your problem?

Comment: As a general idea, a good way to provide "empty" default arguments is to use pointer parameters (instead of references) and use `nullptr` as the default value.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

Note that what you're calling an empty array is actually not an empty array. When we write:

```
int arr[3];
```

This means `arr` is an array of 3 ints whose elements are default initialized. So it is not an empty array.

Below is the working example using templates that shows how to pass array to a function.

**Version 1**: For passing 1D arrays

```
#include <iostream>
template<std::size_t N, std::size_t M>
void foo(const int (&array1)[N], const int (&array2)[M])
{
    std::cout<<"size of passed array1 is: "<<N<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"size of passed array1 is: "<<M<<std::endl;
}


int main()
{
    std::cout<<"Hello World"<<std::endl;
    int arr[] = {1,2,3,4};
    int arr2[] = {1,4};
    foo(arr, arr2);
    return 0;
}
```

**Version 2**: For passing 2D arrays

```
#include <iostream>
template<std::size_t N, std::size_t M>
void foo(const int (&array1)[N][M])
{
    std::cout<<"width of passed array is: "<<N<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"height of passed array2 is: "<<M<<std::endl;
}
int main()
{
    std::cout<<"Hello World"<<std::endl;
    int arr[3][4] = {{0,1,2,3}, {4,5,6,7}, {8,9,10,11}};
    foo(arr);
    
    //now you can pass an array whose elements are default initialized
    int arr2[5][6];
    foo(arr2);
    return 0;
}
```

Also, you can use `std::vector`.